# Ag grid pagination loads previously loaded JSON data from server

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

Form having a  drop down value and a search button,On search will make  server call and grid will populate data.

Grid was loading fine until I added data source for pagination.

### Issue with grid

**Initially it makes 2 same server calls with **start** as 1, and clicking on next it loads previously loaded data in the grid.
On each click on next it loads the json returns in the previous server call.
once it reached last the grid will disappear.
What am I doing wrong here ?**

HTML form, one category drop down and a search button.

```
<div class="col-md-12">  
   <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="searchIncident()" >

    <label for="category">Category</label>
         <select  class="form-control"
            (change)="getSubCategories($event.target.value)"
            formControlName="catCode"   >
            <option value="select" selected disabled>--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let category of categoryMaster" value="{{category.catCode}}">{{category.catDesc}}</option>
         </select>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
   </form>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" *ngIf="rowData.length > 0">  
    <ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 330px;" class="ag-fresh"
        [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
        [columnDefs]="columnDefs"    
        [datasource] = "dataSource"
        enableColResize
        enableSorting
        enableFilter
        rowSelection="single"
    ></ag-grid-angular>
</div>
```

type script  which loads the grid, On submit searchIncident method is called.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import {GridOptions} from "ag-grid/main";
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import * as AppUtils from '../common/app.utils';


export class ISearchComponent {
    myForm: FormGroup;
    rowData: Array<IncidentHeaderModel> = new Array<IncidentHeaderModel>();

    gridOptions = <GridOptions>{
        context: {},
        rowModelType: 'pagination',
        enableServerSideFilter: true,
        paginationPageSize: 10

    };

    columnDefs:any[] = [
     {headerName: 'Incident Id', field: 'incidentId'},
        {headerName: 'Status', field: 'incidentStatus.value'},
        {headerName: 'Category', field: 'categoryMast.catDesc'},
        {headerName: 'Sub Category', field: 'subCategoryMast.subCatDesc'},
        {headerName: 'Location', field: 'location.locName'},
        {headerName: 'Time', field: 'incidentTime'},
        {headerName: 'Delay(Hrs)', cellRenderer:this.getDelayInHours}

    ];

    constructor(private masterDataService:MasterDataService,private http: Http) {
        this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        'catCode'   : new FormControl()

    });
    }

dataSource = {
       pageSize: 10,
        getRows: (params: any) => {
          console.log("here dataSource")
                this.searchIncident(params.startRow, params.endRow); // returns json from server
                var rowsThisPage = this.rowData;
                var lastRow = -1;
//                if (rowsThisPage.length <= params.endRow) {
//                    lastRow = rowsThisPage.length;
//                }
              params.successCallback(rowsThisPage, lastRow);
        }
     }


searchIncident(start:number, end:number){    
  if (!start) {
        start = 1;
      }
  myJson['firstResult'] = start;
  myJson.maxResult = this.gridOptions.paginationPageSize;

   this.http.post(AppUtils.INCIDENT_SEARCH, this.myForm.value, {headers: headers}).subscribe(res=>{
          this.rowData = res.json().result;
         }, err=>{             
         });

    }
}

}
```